# attach file to PHP contact form

Tags: php, email-attachments

i have created a contact for with html and using PHP code to send it my email and its working fine but i have one problem that i want to attach file and to be sent also but i don't know how so anyone can help me with that .... and the php code is below just want to add the attachment of files
thanks in advance

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<!-- Start PHP CODE -->
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// define Errors variables
$fnameErr = $lnameErr = $emailErr = $humanErr = $result =  "" ;
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// define contact form variables
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$design = $_POST['design'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$human = $_POST['human'];
// define Errors variables
$fnameErr = $lnameErr = $emailErr = $humanErr = "" ;
// define Checks variables
$check1 = $check2 = $check3  = $check4 = "";
// define email variables
$to = 'eng.bolaraafat@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Contact Form';
$message = 'From: '.$fname .$lname."\r\n".
           'E-mail: '.$email."\r\n".
           'Telephone: '.$tel."\r\n".
           'Designation: '.$design."\r\n".
           'Country Appled From: '.$country."\r\n".
           'Message: '.$comment."\r\n";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers = "From:" .$email. "\n" ; 
 
// Let's do some checks 
// Checking the First Name
if(empty($_POST["fname"])){
 $fnameErr = "Name is Required";
}else{
 $fname = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
 // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$fname)) {
      $fnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }else{
  $check1 = 1;
 }
}
// Checking the Last Name 
if(empty($_POST["lname"])){
 $lnameErr = "Name is Required";
}else{
 $lname = test_input($_POST["lname"]);
 // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lname)) {
      $lnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }else{
  $check2 = 1;
 }
}
//Checking the Email Adress
if(empty($_POST["email"])){
 $emailErr = "Email is Required";
}else{
 $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
    }else{
  $check3 = 1;
 }
}
//Checking the Anti-Spam Question
if(empty($_POST["human"])){
 $humanErr = "Please Enter the Answer";
}else{
 if ($human != 4){
  $humanErr = "Please check your answer";
 }else{
  $check4 = 1;
 }
}
 
// Emailing the Contents if all Checks are correct 
if($check1 && $check2 && $check3 && $check4 == 1){
 mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
 $result =  "Message Sent Sucessfully";
}else{
 $result = "Message Can't be sent";
}
} 
 function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>
<!-- END OF PHP CODE --> 


<h2>Contact Form</h2>
<p><span style="color: red" >*Required field</span></p>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8">
 First Name:<input type="text" name="fname"><span style="color: red" >*</span>  <?php echo $fnameErr ?> <br><br>
 Last Name:<input type="text" name="lname"><span style="color: red" >*</span> <?php echo $lnameErr ?> <br><br>
 E-mail:<input type="text" name="email"><span style="color: red" >*</span> <?php echo $emailErr ?> <br><br>
 Telephone:<input type="text" name="tel"><br><br>
 Designation:<select name="design">
    <option value="Architectural Engineer">Architectural Engineer</option>
    <option value="Structural Engineer">Structural Engineer</option>
    <option value="Draughts-man">Draughts-man</option>
    <option value="Receptionist">Receptionist</option>
    <option value="Secertary">Secertary</option>
   </select><br><br>
   Country Applied From:<select name="country">
  <option value="">Country...</option>
  <option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
</select><br><br>
 Message:<textarea name="comment"></textarea> <br><br>
 Upload Your Resume:<span style="color: red" >*</span><input type="file" name="uploaded_file"><br><br> 
 <label>*What is 2+2? (Anti-spam)</label>
 <input name="human" placeholder="Type Here"><span style="color: red" >*</span><?php echo $humanErr ?><br><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 <input type="reset" value="Clear">
<?php echo $result ?>
</form><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can send attached picture in email by using `attachment` while sending email

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `PHPMailer` library to send email with attachment's easily

```
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'fromemail@domain.com';
$email->FromName  = 'From Name';
$email->Subject   = 'Your Email Subject';
$email->Body      = $bodytext;
$email->AddAddress( 'toemail@gmail.com' );

$file_to_attach = 'PATH_OF_YOUR_FILE_HERE';

$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'NameOfFile.pdf' );

return $email->Send();
```

Make sure to include `PHPMailer` library. You can get this library from here (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

As per comment request, adding upload code and email code with full example below:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// define Errors variables
$fnameErr = $lnameErr = $emailErr = $humanErr = $result =  "" ;
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
//checking attached file and uploading it to folder
$upload_file_path = '';
if (isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']) && !empty($_FILES['uploaded_file']))    
{
    $dir_path = getcwd();//getting current working directory path
    $upload_dir = $dir_path . 'uploads/';
    if (!file_exists($upload_dir))
    {
        mkdir($upload_dir, 0777, true);
    }
    $file_name = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
    $ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    //validating uploaded file extension
    $valid_extensions = array('pdf', 'doc');//You can customize extension's here

    if (!in_array($ext, $valid_extensions))
    {
        exit('Please use .pdf or .doc file to upload CV.');
    }
    $upload_file_path = $upload_dir . $file_name;

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $upload_file_path);    

}


// Let's do some checks 
// Checking the First Name
if(empty($_POST["fname"])){
    $fnameErr = "Name is Required";
}else{
    $fname = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$fname)) {
      $fnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }else{
        $check1 = 1;
    }
}
// Checking the Last Name   
if(empty($_POST["lname"])){
    $lnameErr = "Name is Required";
}else{
    $lname = test_input($_POST["lname"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lname)) {
      $lnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }else{
        $check2 = 1;
    }
}
//Checking the Email Adress
if(empty($_POST["email"])){
    $emailErr = "Email is Required";
}else{
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
    }else{
        $check3 = 1;
    }
}
//Checking the Anti-Spam Question
if(empty($_POST["human"])){
    $humanErr = "Please Enter the Answer";
}else{
    if ($human != 4){
        $humanErr = "Please check your answer";
    }else{
        $check4 = 1;
    }
}

// Emailing the Contents if all Checks are correct  
if($check1 && $check2 && $check3 && $check4 == 1){
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    $result =  "Message Sent Sucessfully";
}else{
    $result = "Message Can't be sent";
}
} 
 function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

// define contact form variables
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$design = $_POST['design'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$human = $_POST['human'];
// define Errors variables
$fnameErr = $lnameErr = $emailErr = $humanErr = "" ;
// define Checks variables
$check1 = $check2 = $check3  = $check4 = "";
// define email variables
$to = 'eng.bolaraafat@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Contact Form';
$message = 'From: '.$fname .$lname."\r\n".
           'E-mail: '.$email."\r\n".
           'Telephone: '.$tel."\r\n".
           'Designation: '.$design."\r\n".
           'Country Appled From: '.$country."\r\n".
           'Message: '.$comment."\r\n";

$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'fromemail@domain.com';//Your From Email
$email->FromName  = $fname;
$email->Subject   = $subject;
$email->Body      = $message;
$email->AddAddress( $email );

if (!empty($upload_file_path))
{
    $email->AddAttachment( $upload_file_path , 'CV_'.time().'.pdf' );
}

return $email->Send();



?>
```

Try this and let me know if you are having any issue. Also please make sure to include `phpmailer` library on top of your php file.

Comment: @ Mahesh Singh Chouhan actaully i want to attach pdf and doc for cv also i know about php mailer but really i dont know how to use it thats why i asked for php code or else if u have any reference to php mailer please send me.... thanks for your help really

Comment: Do you want me to add `upload` file code too with email code? As i can see you have not added php file upload code in your php code.

Comment: what i need is to attach file with this contact form so that it will be sent to my mail when the user press submit .... so i dont know if its needed to upload it and uploaded it where ... i have watched hundred of videos but nothing helped all i need is to attach a pdf or doc or docx files so when user press submit i can recieve the file on my pc .... and really thanks for your patience i appreciate it

Comment: Okay let me update answer with upload file code, so that you can have uploaded file on your machine.

Comment: thank you in advance i swear  i don't believe that someone will help me as easy as that i really appreciate what you did to me ... thanks alot

Comment: updated answer with upload code with valid file extension like pdf, doc Use this php code and let me know if you are having any issue in the process. Thanks

Comment: Hey @paulrf, also mark this answer as useful after php implementation so that it can help others too. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Mahesh Singh Chouhan i have marked your answer but really i have alot of errors also my question was trying to find a way to attach file with `mail()` as i found your answer before in the below link but i marked it coz it may help others also for your big effort you did to help me and thanks again for your help 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail